# Gitlab showing "An error occurred while fetching folder content."

Tags: docker, gitlab

I accidentally messed up with the file owners (chown on the wrong level...) on my self-hosted Gitlab running in a Docker container. I managed to restore most of the ownerships.

This was done by running `docker exec gitlab_container_name update-permissions`. However, this did not immediately fix the problem as the logs still showed a permission denied error for the grafana db. In oder to fix this, I continued by setting up a fresh Gitlab and comparing/restoring the ownership.

While Gitlab itself is now running again, I still get the following errors:

1. When I try to push, I receive:

```
remote: GitLab: Push operation timed out
remote:
remote: Timing information for debugging purposes:
remote: Running checks for ref: XXXX
remote: Checking if you are allowed to push... (62.94ms)
remote: Checking if default branch is being deleted... (0.31ms)
remote: Scanning repository for blobs stored in LFS and verifying their files have been uploaded to GitLab... (cancelled after 29547.57ms)
To http://gitlab.XXXX.XX/XXXX/XXXX.git
 ! [remote rejected]   XXXXX -> XXXX (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'http://gitlab.XXXX.XX/XXXX/XXXX.git'
```

2. When I click on a project in the web UI it shows information such as the branches, total file size, etc., but not the list of files/files itself. Rather `**An error occurred while fetching folder content.**` is displayed.

Running `gitlab-ctl tail` while trying to push shows the following:

```
{"level":"info","msg":"I, [2021-07-05T17:13:19.676164 #3372254]  INFO -- sentry: ** [Raven] Raven 3.0.4 configured not to capture errors: DSN not set","supervisor.args":["bundle","exec","bin/ruby-cd","/var/opt/gitlab/gitaly","/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitaly-ruby/bin/gitaly-ruby","3368488","/var/opt/gitlab/gitaly/internal_sockets/ruby.0"],"supervisor.name":"gitaly-ruby.0","time":"2021-07-05T17:13:19.692Z"}
{"error":"exit status 1","level":"warning","msg":"exited","supervisor.args":["bundle","exec","bin/ruby-cd","/var/opt/gitlab/gitaly","/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitaly-ruby/bin/gitaly-ruby","3368488","/var/opt/gitlab/gitaly/internal_sockets/ruby.0"],"supervisor.name":"gitaly-ruby.0","time":"2021-07-05T17:13:19.698Z"}
{"level":"info","msg":"I, [2021-07-05T17:13:20.817759 #3372257]  INFO -- sentry: ** [Raven] Raven 3.0.4 configured not to capture errors: DSN not set","supervisor.args":["bundle","exec","bin/ruby-cd","/var/opt/gitlab/gitaly","/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitaly-ruby/bin/gitaly-ruby","3368488","/var/opt/gitlab/gitaly/internal_sockets/ruby.1"],"supervisor.name":"gitaly-ruby.1","time":"2021-07-05T17:13:20.835Z"}
{"error":"exit status 1","level":"warning","msg":"exited","supervisor.args":["bundle","exec","bin/ruby-cd","/var/opt/gitlab/gitaly","/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitaly-ruby/bin/gitaly-ruby","3368488","/var/opt/gitlab/gitaly/internal_sockets/ruby.1"],"supervisor.name":"gitaly-ruby.1","time":"2021-07-05T17:13:20.843Z"}
[...]
{"correlation_id":"01F9VTFEM5X7N2PZR6WVDAQQYN","error":"GitLab: Push operation timed out\n\nTiming information for debugging purposes:\nRunning checks for ref: XXXX\nChecking if you are allowed to push... (13.42ms)\nChecking if default branch is being deleted... (0.43ms)\nScanning repository for blobs stored in LFS and verifying their files have been uploaded to GitLab... (cancelled after 29583.1ms)","grpc.meta.deadline_type":"none","grpc.method":"PreReceiveHook","grpc.request.fullMethod":"/gitaly.HookService/PreReceiveHook","grpc.request.glProjectPath":"XXXX/XXXX","grpc.request.glRepository":"project-5","grpc.request.repoPath":"@hashed/ef/2d/ef2d127de37b942baad06145e54b0c619a1f22327b2ebbcfbec78f5564afe39d.git","grpc.request.repoStorage":"default","grpc.request.topLevelGroup":"@hashed","grpc.service":"gitaly.HookService","grpc.start_time":"2021-07-05T17:11:59.178Z","level":"warning","msg":"stopping transaction because pre-receive hook failed","peer.address":"@","pid":3368488,"span.kind":"server","system":"grpc","time":"2021-07-05T17:12:29.025Z"}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

EDIT: I sdded the information about `docker exec gitlab_container_name update-permissions` as discussed in the comments.

Comment: Gitlab comes with a script to set the permissions correctly on your instance. If your docker container is already running, you should be able to fix the problem issuing the following command: `docker exec your_gitlab_container_name update-permissions`. For more info, you can see the [source of the script](https://github.com/gitlabhq/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/docker/assets/update-permissions).

Comment: @Zeitounator, yes, I forgot to mention that I started from there. I still had to manually update the permissions in the grafana folder (as this caused some permission denied errors in the logs).

Comment: It's still time to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68259947/edit) you answer to add all the things you have tried in detail so that no one else looses time trying to help you with tips you have already applied. Meanwhile, this question is not related to programming and would certainly be more suited for https://superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this by setting up a new Gitlab Docker container and by following the instructions from the documentation to backup and restore Gitlab (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/raketasks/backup_restore.html).

Note that is important to also backup the secrets from the following files:

```
/etc/gitlab/gitlab-secrets.json
/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb
```

The process is really easy and smooth and depending on the file size of your repository it only takes a couple of minutes to backup and restore.